# Ansible to automate dev environment setup

Tags: bash, linux, ansible

This is a follow-up to [Bash script to automate dev environment setup](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249244/bash-script-to-automate-dev-environment-setup).

In that question I'd thrown together a (sloppy) shell script to automatically setup my development environment. One of the answers suggested using Ansible and after a bit of reading realized it would help me with some configuration of remote servers as well so I decided to give it a go.

Below is playbook that sets up my dev environment the same way as the original bash script but hopefully a bit cleaner. I'm planning on using Ansible to setup a new CI/CD pipeline in a reproducible way as a replacement for the github -> dockerhub -> manual deployment so this is really testing the waters with Ansible before moving on to that.

Right now it all I need to do is clone the repo the two files are in and then run bootstrap.sh and everything gets set up from there.

Any/all pointers appreciated!

bootstrap.sh:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
sudo apt install -y ansible
mv AnsibleDevEnv/setup.yml ~/
ansible-playbook setup.yml
. .bash_profile
```

And then the Ansible playbook setup.yml:

```
---
- name: Dev Setup
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
  
    folders:
    - go
    - python
    - js
    - pemKeys
    
    downloads:
      url:
      - https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x
      - https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh
      - https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/getgo/installer_linux

      sudo_files:
      - setup_14.x
       - Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh
        
      user_files:
      - installer_linux
      
    keys:
      - https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
      - https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg
      
    repos:
      - deb [trusted=yes arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian {{ docker_version.stdout }} stable
      - deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
      
    packages:
      - apt-transport-https 
      - ca-certificates 
      - gnupg2 
      - software-properties-common
      - libgl1-mesa-glx 
      - libegl1-mesa 
      - libxrandr2 
      - libxrandr2 
      - libxss1 
      - libxcursor1 
      - libxcomposite1 
      - libasound2 
      - libxi6 
      - libxtst6
      - libpq-dev 
      - python3-dev
      - python3-pip
      - protobuf-compiler
      - apt-transport-https
      - code
      - nodejs
      - postgresql-11
      - docker-ce
      
    node_lib:
      - react
      - react-scripts
      - react-dom
      
    go_get:
      - go get github.com/lib/pq
      - export
      - GO111MODULE=on go get github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
      - GO111MODULE=on go get -u google.golang.org/grpc
      
    pip:
      - psycopg2
      
    git_config:
      name: 
        - user.name
        - user.email
        - color.ui
      value:
        - cmelgreen
        - cmelgreen@gmail.com
        - true

  tasks:
    - name: make folders
      file:
        path: './{{ item }}'
        mode: 0755
        state: directory
      with_items: '{{ folders }}'
      
    - name: install rpm
      apt:
        name: rpm
        state: latest
        update_cache: yes
      become: yes
        
    - name: add keys
      apt_key:
        state: present
        url: '{{ item }}'
      with_items: '{{ keys }}'
      become: yes
      
    - name: save docker version to variable
      shell: lsb_release -cs
      register: docker_version
      
    - name: add repositories
      apt_repository: 
        repo: '{{ item }}'
        state: present
      with_items: '{{ repos }}'
      become: yes
        
    - name: download files
      get_url: 
        url: '{{ item }}'
        dest: .
        mode: +x
      with_items: '{{ downloads.url }}'
        
    - name: run as root downloads
      command: './{{ item }}'
      with_items: '{{ downloads.sudo_files }}'
      become: yes
      
    - name: run as user downloads
      command: './{{ item }}'
      with_items: '{{ downloads.user_files }}'

    - name: add source ./.bashrc to .bash_profile
      lineinfile:
        path: ./.bash_profile
        line: 'source ./.bashrc'
        
    - name: install packages
      apt: 
        name: '{{ packages }}'
        state: latest
        update_cache: yes
      become: yes
       
    - name: set docker permissions
      file:
        path: /var/run/docker.sock
        mode: 0666
      become: yes

    - name: install react
      npm:
        name: '{{ item }}'
        global: yes
        state: latest
      with_items: '{{ node_lib }}'
      become: yes

    - name: go get some libraries
      shell: '. ~/.bash_profile && {{ item }}'
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
      with_items: '{{ go_get }}'


    - name: pip some stuff conda has a hard time with
      pip:
        name: '{{ pip }}'
```

Comment: You could add [`vagant`](https://www.vagrantup.com/) to your toolkit which you can use to spin up an environment (i.e. virtual machine, AWS EC2 instance, ..) and [provision the instance directly with your new `ansible-playbook`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible) then it's just up [`vagrant up`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/up) to get your reproducible environments and [`vagrant destroy`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/destroy) to tear them down when you're done.

Comment: Would that work on a local machine? I'm literally working on Jenkins configuration as code right now so I can deploy the build servers with full automation using Terraform that's another Hashicorp system but the above is for my local envrionment. There's not a away round at least a short bootstrap bash script is there, even with vagrant? Like something needs to be installed first. Because I play semi-loose with my environment and test things out that occasionally break it all so it's easier to just nuke and rebuild while I grab a coffee

Comment: The end goal of everything being you could wipe everything but my GitHub account and aws credentials and with one or to commands spin up everything from scratch

Comment: Yes, is made for it. I used to use `vagrant` + `virtualbox` locally for running and provisioning a VM using `ansible-playbooks` then when I was happy with the deployment specs I'd use the same `ansible-playbooks` to provision AWS EC2 instances (slightly different because I build AMI's on schedule using `packer` for production). Is basically a CLI for managing VM's with their own config and provisioner hooks. There also exists a [shell provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell) for executing shell commands after the machine is created and before the `ansible-playbook` run.

Comment: Using `vagrant` you can bring it down to a single command for provisioning the dev environment (`vagrant up`: will create a VM, execute shell commands then run `ansible-playbook`'s) then purge it with `vagrant destroy` when you're done with it. [I have an example project](https://github.com/masseybradley/playground) (albeit a little outdated) to bootstrap 3 VM's using `vagrant` then install `docker` and configure 
 `docker swarm` using an `ansible-playbook`. Nowadays irl I'd suggest all the things in `docker`! \o/

Comment: If you're deploying to AWS (or developing in AWS) there exists a [`vagrant-aws`](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws) plugin.